# iPhone Jack Audio Input as USB port for custom devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

Im sure that's possible to use Jack Audio Input as simple data input. But it's possible to use it as USB port then programmatically read data as usb does ? It's necessary to make cool accessory. And question #2 - does iPhone lighting port can provide 5v ?

Answer (score 0):

> But it's possible to use [the audio port] as USB port then programmatically read data as usb does ?

The iPhone audio port is an audio port. It is not a general-purpose I/O, and cannot be used for a USB device.

> does iPhone lighting port can provide 5v ?

Maybe. The Lightning port can clearly provide power to run certain accessories (e.g, the SD card reader), but there is no public information on what voltage is involved. You will need to join the Apple [MFi Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) to get details.

Comment: But acutally, iPhone audio port can be technically used as data input. It's tweaky solution. BUT possible. https://code.google.com/archive/p/hijack-main/ I was wondering if its possible to use it as custom usb input.

Comment: It can only be used for very limited, specific tasks which can be adapted to run over audio. Definitely not USB.